# Browse Api - multiple categories not working as expected

Tags: here-api

According to the docs, a list of categories can be passed to the browse api to get specific types of locations/businesses.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-browse-brief.html

However, it looks like some results are missing when sending a mix of level 1, level 2, and level 3 categories.

ex: The following lat/lng is the exact location of a bar called Liberty in Austin, TX.

If a level 1 category is passed by itself, then Liberty shows up.

```
https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=30.26271,-97.72524&limit=20&categories=100&apiKey=
```

However, if the same query is sent with the brewery level 3 category passed, then it only returns breweries and Liberty is missing.

```
https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=30.26271,-97.72524&limit=20&categories=100,300-3000-0350&apiKey=
```

Are the docs incorrect/ambiguous or is there something incorrect about how this is being called?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using code "300-3000-0023" or "700-7460-0115". They are for level3 categories code for tourist attractions and tourist information

https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=30.26271,-97.72524&limit=100&categories=300-3000-0023,300-3000-0350&apiKey=XXXX